# How can I use ffmpeg to join multiple MP4 videos together that are various resolutions?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use FFmpeg to join together multiple MP4 videos, however, the videos are all different resolutions (width, height) and FFmpeg keeps throwing errors when trying to concatenate the clips.

Im using this command to try and concatenate the clips:

```
ffmpeg -i [PATH TO 1ST CLIP] -i [PATH TO 2ND CLIP] \-filter_complex "[0:v] [0:a] [1:v] [1:a] \concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" -map "[v]" \-map "[a]" [OUTPUT PATH]
```

But when I run this command I get the following errors:

```
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x7fd6a1d09340] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 1242x1030, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (1124x1142, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0x7fd6a1d09340] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #1:0
Conversion failed!
```

Does anyone know what command I should use to join these clips together?

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** join any 2 videos with different resolutions, at least not with `ffmpeg`. It's mentioned explicitly in the `ffmpeg concat` docs that you will have to do it manually before concatenation. Src: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat

> All corresponding streams must have the same parameters in all segments; the filtering system will automatically select a common pixel format for video streams, and a common sample format, sample rate and channel layout for audio streams, but other settings, such as resolution, must be converted explicitly by the user.